# How to make a select box with a rotatable camera in unity?

Tags: unity, 3d

How to make a select box with a rotatable camera in unity?

this is my camera [image: Cam]

The way the camera rotates is to rotate the main camera, which is a child object from the parent object, around the origin.
And this camera can zoom in and zoom out.

When a selection is made in this camera, a rectangle is drawn in real time with the line renderer.

I made a bound in real time through this and tried using boxcastall, but there is a problem that the bound region itself becomes strange.

I really don't know how to fix this.

Goal: use of other methods or
create accurate bounds

How can I make the bounds exactly like the rectangle I drew?

```
 else if (CameraManager.S.mouseClickMode == MouseClickMode.Boxtool
            && Input.GetMouseButton(0))
        {
            //green box vertex 
            Vector3 mousePos1 = mainCamera.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(startMouseInputPos.x,
           Input.mousePosition.y, mainCamera.nearClipPlane * 1 / mainCamera.nearClipPlane));
            Vector3 mousePos3 = mainCamera.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x,
          startMouseInputPos.y, mainCamera.nearClipPlane * 1 / mainCamera.nearClipPlane));
            currentLineRenderer.SetPosition(1, mousePos1);
            currentLineRenderer.SetPosition(2, mousePos1);

            currentLineRenderer.SetPosition(3, GetMousePosition());
            currentLineRenderer.SetPosition(4, GetMousePosition());

            currentLineRenderer.SetPosition(5, mousePos3);
            currentLineRenderer.SetPosition(6, mousePos3);

            currentLineRenderer.SetPosition(7, startPosition);

            bounds.Encapsulate(startPosition);
            bounds.Encapsulate(mousePos1);
            bounds.Encapsulate(GetMousePosition());
            bounds.Encapsulate(mousePos3);
        }
        else if (CameraManager.S.mouseClickMode == MouseClickMode.Boxtool
           && Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
        {

          

            BoxSelectionMakePlane();

            BoxCollider col =boxCol.GetComponent<BoxCollider>();
            col.center = bounds.center;
            col.size = bounds.size;


            testCube.transform.position = col.bounds.min;
            testCube1.transform.position = col.bounds.max;
            string str = null;
            Quaternion quaternion = Quaternion.identity;
            //Collider[] hitColliders = Physics.OverlapBox(bounds.center, bounds.size / 2);
            RaycastHit[] hitColliders = Physics.BoxCastAll(bounds.center, bounds.size / 2,mainCamera.transform.forward,
                quaternion,20f, 1 << 8);
            Debug.Log(hitColliders.Length);
            foreach (var item in hitColliders)
            {
                str+=(item.transform.gameObject.name)+" ";
            }
            Debug.Log(str);
        }
    }

    
    Vector3 GetMousePosition()
    {
        Vector3 mousePos = mainCamera.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x,
            Input.mousePosition.y, mainCamera.nearClipPlane *1/ mainCamera.nearClipPlane));
      
        return mousePos;
    }
```

```
bounds.SetMinMax(startPosition, GetMousePosition());
```

[image: this]
bounds.center bounds.size is set .

Since bounds are adjusted based on the center, the method using set min max is inevitably not correct if it is tilted.

i found [bound](https://forum.unity.com/threads/i-dont-understand-what-col-bounds-max-x-means.1084511/)

[image: error bounds]

Comment: Can you define your problem more precisely than "becomes strange"? What do you observe? How specifically does this differ from what you want?

Comment: @DMGregory  If you look at the picture above, the bounds I want are holding the rectangular bounds based on that green 2d ui.
But those bounds seen through the coilider are in a completely different location.

Comment: Try sketching for us what you would like to see instead.

Comment: @DMGregory I want to get exactly the bounds of the plane made by the green line in that first collider picture.

Comment: @DMGregory The problem is that when you draw a rectangle on a screen which shows a perspective view of a 3d plane, then the resulting shape on the 3d plane is a trapezoid. And Unity unfortunately has no `Physics.OverlapTrapezoid` method out-of-the-box.